# Converting a grid defined via XAML to its C# equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I'd like to convert the following XAML sample code into its C# equivalent:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!-- Sub-grid on left -->
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Left, Row 0" Background="Azure" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Content="Left, Row 2" Background="Lavender" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>

<!-- Sub-grid on right -->
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Right, Row 0" Background="Moccasin" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label Content="Right, Row 2" Background="Honeydew" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>

<!-- Splitter between left/right sub-grids -->
<GridSplitter Grid.Column ="1" Width="8" Background="DarkSlateBlue"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This is my code so far:

```
    Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
ColumnDefinition gridColDef0 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition gridColDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
gridColDef1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
ColumnDefinition gridColDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef0);
DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef1);
DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef2);
RowDefinition gridRowDef0 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition gridRowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
gridRowDef1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
RowDefinition gridRowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
```

But I don't know how to add the grid row definitions to column 0. I'd have expected something along the lines of DynamicGrid.Columns[0].RowDefinitions.Add, but I haven't found such a thing. Can you help me? Thanks!

Edit: For future reference, here's the equivalent C# code. Mind you, it can be optimized!

```
private void CreateDynamicWPFGrid()
    {
        // Create the Grid
        Grid dynamicGrid = new Grid();

        ColumnDefinition gridColDef0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition gridColDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        gridColDef1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
        ColumnDefinition gridColDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();

        dynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef0);
        dynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef1);
        dynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef2);

        // Sub-grid on left.
        {
            Grid leftSubGrid = new Grid();

            RowDefinition gridRowDef0 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition gridRowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
            gridRowDef1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
            RowDefinition gridRowDef2 = new RowDefinition();

            leftSubGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef0);
            leftSubGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef1);
            leftSubGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef2);

            Label label;
            label = new Label();
            label.Content = "Left, Row 0";
            label.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Azure);
            Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
            leftSubGrid.Children.Add(label);

            label = new Label();
            label.Content = "Left, Row 2";
            label.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lavender);
            Grid.SetRow(label, 2);
            leftSubGrid.Children.Add(label);

            GridSplitter gridSplitter = new GridSplitter();
            gridSplitter.Height = 8;
            gridSplitter.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateBlue);
            gridSplitter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            gridSplitter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetRow(gridSplitter, 1);
            leftSubGrid.Children.Add(gridSplitter);

            Grid.SetColumn(leftSubGrid, 0);
            dynamicGrid.Children.Add(leftSubGrid);
        }

        // Sub-grid on right.
        {
            Grid rightSubGrid = new Grid();

            RowDefinition gridRowDef0 = new RowDefinition();
            RowDefinition gridRowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
            gridRowDef1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
            RowDefinition gridRowDef2 = new RowDefinition();

            rightSubGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef0);
            rightSubGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef1);
            rightSubGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef2);

            Label label;
            label = new Label();
            label.Content = "Left, Row 0";
            label.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Moccasin);
            Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
            rightSubGrid.Children.Add(label);

            label = new Label();
            label.Content = "Left, Row 2";
            label.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Honeydew);
            Grid.SetRow(label, 2);
            rightSubGrid.Children.Add(label);

            GridSplitter gridSplitter = new GridSplitter();
            gridSplitter.Height = 8;
            gridSplitter.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateBlue);
            gridSplitter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            gridSplitter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            Grid.SetRow(gridSplitter, 1);
            rightSubGrid.Children.Add(gridSplitter);

            Grid.SetColumn(rightSubGrid, 2);
            dynamicGrid.Children.Add(rightSubGrid);
        }

        {
            GridSplitter gridSplitter = new GridSplitter();
            gridSplitter.Width = 8;
            gridSplitter.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkSlateBlue);
            gridSplitter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            gridSplitter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            Grid.SetColumn(gridSplitter, 1);
            dynamicGrid.Children.Add(gridSplitter);
        }

        // Display grid into a Window
        Content = dynamicGrid;
    }
```

Comment: You don't add row definitions to columns. And you're already adding the row definitions and column definitions. What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML represents a grid of grids -- i.e. the outer grid has one row with three columns. each "cell" contains a single grid with three rows each, and a single column.

Your code version only has a single Grid.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't noticed that! I wrote the code based on your suggestion and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection of RowDefinitions in your grid (as ColumnsDefinitions).
For each control, you should set column/row in order to put in in the grid.

Try this:

```
    Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
    ColumnDefinition gridColDef0 = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition gridColDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    gridColDef1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
    ColumnDefinition gridColDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef0);
    DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef1);
    DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridColDef2);
    RowDefinition gridRowDef0 = new RowDefinition();
    RowDefinition gridRowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
    gridRowDef1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
    RowDefinition gridRowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
    DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef0);
    DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef1);
    DynamicGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRowDef2);

    Label label= new Label ();
    Grid.SetColumn(label, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(label, 0);
```

Just apply this concept to your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your suggestion about using SetRow and SetColumn was useful, but the real problem was that I had a grid inside a grid, as suggested by Rowland Shaw.